# Django: Do I need not to think about 'select_related' or 'prefetch_related' if I used 'django-cachalot'?

Tags: django

I found that `django-cachalot`(http://django-cachalot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which looks very good for caching for novice.

If I used this library, Do I need not to use `select_related` or `prefetch_related`? For example, Can I use just

```
class ClienListView(LoginRequiredMixin, AjaxListView):
    model = ClienPost
    context_object_name = "posts"
    template_name = "clien/clien_list.html"
    page_template = 'clien/clien_list_page.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        posts = ClienPost.objects.all()
        return posts
```

instead of

```
class ClienListView(LoginRequiredMixin, AjaxListView):
    model = ClienPost
    context_object_name = "posts"
    template_name = "clien/clien_list.html"
    page_template = 'clien/clien_list_page.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        posts = ClienPost.objects.select_related('category').prefetch_related('cliencomment_set').all()
        return posts
```

??

Comment: don't worry about caching until speed is a problem.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood I posted this question because speed is a problem

Comment: well, using a module such as "timeit" you can determine if the code runs faster with or without the _related instructions.